# Validation in Spring with different Roles

Tags: spring, forms, validation, spring-mvc

I'm just trying to understand the "Validation" within Spring MVC. I set up a small validation form, which is working just fine. However I got a couple of questions all those Tutorials don't answer

As far as I understood the Validator just gets every form-element altered and checks if it is valid or not. What if I want a user to only be able to alter specific form-elements.

Let's say I have an Admin and a regular User on my webpage, they both are allowed to edit their profiles. The admin however is allowed to alter his username, the regular isn't allowed to do that. They both use the "edit-profile.jsp" and therefore the same Validator. I could just grey out the username field in my regular user's view, but let's assume he's not a total BDU and adds a form-field via debugger of his webbrowser, overriding the actual username input-field. He then alters his username and sends the request to MVC. The validator assumes the username altered came from the original input-field and updates the user's nickname in the db accordingly, since both, the admin and the regular user just use the same Validator and the same "updateAllAltered"-DAO method. The same goes for select option-lists. Let's say the Admin is allowed to set a status of a profile to active AND inactive. The user however is only allowed to set it's own profile to inactive but can't reactivate it by himself. I could do the same as above, just altering the option-panel in the frontend to only show "INACTIVE" in the regular user's dropdown box. But we could repeat the same scenario, where the user just adds a debug form-field containing also the option "ACTIVE". This can get out of hand if e.g. the Admin is allowed to change Roles to "admin, member, moderator", while a user, who's i.e. a moderator within a forum can change roles to "member or moderator". He could just again add another field and plugin "admin" and gain total control of the forum.

How is this handled in Spring?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have to handle by spring security for your use case, design your application security, you will find basic spring security examples easily.

Example you can block your HTML code in JSP by spring security tags by user roles.

```
<sec:authorize access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
                                <a href="delete/${file.id}">Delete</a>
                            </sec:authorize>
```

You can annotate any of your methods by roles to block access.

```
@Secured({ "ROLE_ADMIN" })
```

Comment: Well, that still doesn't solve the problem of the http-request. The update()-function, which is a DAO-method to update a user's record is called from the regular user, as well as from the admin. So both have access to that method. The frontend method with <sec:autohorize> just hides the link, if you are not an admin, but if you were to hack that button back into the form via a debugger you could still press "Delete" as a standard-non-admin user. So the backend would have to distinct between admin and user allowed fields, which got sent via the http-request.

Comment: no you cant press delete as non-admin user because your delete method is @Secured  for only ROLE_ADMIN..May be you need to separate your DAO methods for users and admin and annotate Secured respectively..

Comment: Add you will have spring security filter chain intercepting your initial http request who manages the user's session and his roles by verifying with some user db or ldap so that no one can tamper the roles of current user logged in session.